# Does INACTIVE sessions in Oracle is normal ? Is it Impacted on ORA-02391 Exceeded simultaneous session_per_user limit?

Tags: database, oracle, session

I am facing the ORA-02391 for one user. My application keeping more Inactive session in oracle database. ORA-02391 is related to the inactive sessions or only parallel sessions of active connection please clarify.

When and How Inactive sessions for Oracle are removed ?

Comment: get the profile nam from dba_users where username='USER';  then from dba_profiles get the limit of the user where resource_name  = 'SESSIONS_PER_USER',  and yes is related to inactive session and you can remove them by killing them

Comment: @moudiz Thanks for your rely,My application contains Hibernate timout of 300 sec, means after the 5min(300 sec) Inactive sessions should be removed. How do i validate that is happening, besause I still have more inactive onnection in oracle database. ORA-02391, can only be resolved with increasing user profile configuration ?

Comment: from v$sql you can get get the inactive and active sessions `selecT  username,status from v$session`, and try to kill the inactive(but make sure for whom it belongs then try).. and yes try to increase the the profile